# Setting Android Platform on Mac OS

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am installing android working environment on mac. I have installed Eclipse. I installed the android plugins as described in the manual. I went to 'help' and 'check for new software' but when I entered the site url, it shows following error:

Some sites could not be found.  See the error log for more detail.
No repository found at https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse..
HTTP Method Not Allowed: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html/content.xml
HttpClient connection error response code 405.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the following operating systems are supported:
Windows XP or Vista
Mac OS X 10.4.8 or later (x86 only)
Linux (tested on Linux Ubuntu Dapper Drake)
You will also need to install a suitable development environment such as:
Eclipse
Eclipse 3.2, 3.3 (Europa)
Android Development Tools plugin (optional)
Other development environments or IDEs
JDK 5 or JDK 6 (JRE alone is not sufficient)
Not compatible with Gnu Compiler for Java (gcj)
Apache Ant 1.6.5 or later for Linux and Mac, 1.7 or later for Windows
Installing The Android SDK

First you will need to download the Android SDK pack .zip archive, once downloaded find a suitable installation location on your machine and extract the zipped files.
Please note: This installation location will be referred to as $SDK_ROOT from now on through this tutorial
Alternatively you can add /tools to your root path which will prevent the need to specify the full path to the tools directory along with enabling you to run Android Debug Bridge (adb) along with other command line tools.
To add /tools:
Linux
Edit the ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc files looking for a line that sets the PATH variable.
Add the full path location to your $SDK_ROOT/tools location for the PATH variable.
If no PATH line exists you can add the line by typing the following:
export PATH=${PATH}:
Mac OS X
In the home directory locate the .bash_profile and locating the PATH variable add the location to your $SDK_ROOT/tools folder.

Comment: when i donwload Android pluging its not downloading